# How to display a background image larger than the actual div size?

Tags: html, css, image

I want to display image larger then the actual div size and scroll it inside the div.

The image should be behind the div and part of the image are hide.

To view all the image i should scroll it.

[demojsFFidle](http://jsfiddle.net/centerwow/BZeLR/29/)

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <img src="http://i53.tinypic.com/2ymznmx.jpg" width="100" height="100" />
</div>

#wrapper {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width:80px;
  height;80px;
  margin:10px;
  z-index:4;
}
img {
    border: 1px solid red;
   display: inline-block;
}
```

many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may add `overflow:auto;` to the `#wrapper` div.
This way, the scroll bar will be shown only when it is needed.

You may add `overflow:hidden;` if you do not want to show the scroll bars at all.

JSFiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/BZeLR/30/

Answer (score 1):

add `overflow: scroll;` to your div. This will allow the user to scroll inside of the div to view the background.

Comment: Add it to the style rule, not the div :)

Comment: Did it possible to get the same resualt and to hide the scroll bar ?

Comment: @Ken-AbdiasSoftware Yea, yea, yea :) I knew what I meant hah

Comment: @user1954217 I'm not sure how the user would know to scroll without a scroll bar.

Comment: The user should not know I make a game and the code will do it. not user not manual

Answer (score 0):

To display the image behind the div... try using z-index property...and also add a scroll to your css...

something like...

```
your_css {
z-index:2;
overflow:scroll;
}
```

might help...